# Split long string by adding delimiters

Tags: unix, sed, split

I'm having an issue on a file I have.
It has 3 columns and the last one contains a huge text field.
It came from an Oracle's CLob so it can be 4k long...

I want to integrate it in my Oracle, but I can't manage to import the file.

Is it possible to add some delimiters on each line to split those huge lines?
Let's say, add a '|' (my delimiter) every 200 characters or something like that so I can import small part by small part?

The trick will be to add consecutive delimiters when the lines do not have a huge length

**For example:**
Raw files:

```
12345678910
12345
```

Will be transformed into (if I have a char every 5)

```
12345|67891|0
12345||
```

Do you think it's possible using a perl or sed ?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit: just to clear it up:
I need the same number of fields throughout the file. So the longest line will define how much fields I need per line in my whole file. And the text of the file contains sentences of people.

Thanks a lot for your help guys.

Comment: how come `12345` outputs `12345||`?

Comment: Becaus I need the same number of fields throughout the file. So the longest line will define how much fields I need per line in my whole file.

Comment: ah, that's painful. you need to scan through the file twice. first walk you need to find the longest line. then generate the pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 12345678901234567890 | sed 's/\(.\{5\}\)/\1|/g'
```

gives

```
12345|67890|12345|67890|
```

Adjust the number between the braces for longer chunks.

EDIT: Since the comments to the question cleared up the requirements, I hacked something together with awk that finds the field count in a first pass and splices in separators in a second:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -v width=5 '                 # adjust width as required
  BEGIN { maxlen = 0 }
  NR == FNR {                    # first pass
    if(length($0) > maxlen) {
      maxlen = length($0)        # just find the longest line.
    }
    next
  }
  {                              # second pass
    fieldcount = maxlen / width  # splice in separators
    line = ""
    for(i = 0; i < fieldcount; ++i) {
      line = line substr($0, 1 + i * width, width) "|"
    }
    print line                   # then print line.
  }
' foo.txt foo.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Wintermute. Maybe I'm doing this wrong but I put your code in a sh right (I call it test.sh)? then I use the command ./test.sh. But I have a synthax error

Comment: Works for me, but if your shell doesn't like it for some reason, you can put the stuff between the `'` in a file of its own, say `foo.awk`, and call `awk -f foo.awk -v width=5 foo.txt foo.txt` instead.

Answer (score 0):

sed script

```
sed '
/^.\{0,5\}$/ {
s/\(^.*$\)/&||/g
}
/^.\{5,\}[^|]$/ {
s/.\{5\}/&|/g
} '
```

or

```
sed '/^.\{0,5\}$/ {s/\(^.*$\)/&||/g};/^.\{5,\}[^|]$/ {s/.\{5\}/&|/g}'
```

This script will add `||` if any line has 0-5 characters **only**, if the line has more than five characters the script will add a `|` **every** 5 characters on that line

let say you have the numbers in a file called `my_file`

```
123456789100986093486084
12345
81638164864
126817
2394
2347
9487298579275934636975697w8
12
```

**command line**

```
sed '
/^.\{0,5\}$/ {
s/\(^.*$\)/&||/g
}
/^.\{5,\}[^|]$/ {
s/.\{5\}/&|/g
} ' 'my_file'
```

or

```
sed '/^.\{0,5\}$/ {s/\(^.*$\)/&||/g};/^.\{5,\}[^|]$/ {s/.\{5\}/&|/g}' 'my_file'
```

**results**

```
12345|67891|00986|09348|6084
12345||
81638|16486|4
12681|7
2394||
2347||
94872|98579|27593|46369|75697|w8
12||
```

**how the script works**

```
   /^.\{0,5\}$/ {
    s/\(^.*$\)/&||/g
    }
```

the first part of the script checks for all lines that have 0-5 characters. if true, it will add `||` at the end of these lines

```
   /^.\{5,\}[^|]$/ {
    s/.\{5\}/&|/g
    } '
```

this part of the script searches for all lines that have 5 or more characters that does not end with `||`, if these lines are found, for  every 5 characters it will add `|`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{5\}\)/\1|/g' file name.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.\{5\}/&|/g;s/^.\{0,4\}/&|||/' YourFile
```

- Add a `|` every 5 character
- Add `|||` at the end if length is max 4 character